# the main measure

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question, translation-request, mathematical-french

I'm looking for the following notion in english if exists, called in french "la mesure principale" ( the main measure )

[image]

Let $\theta$ be an angle in standard position the main measure for $\theta$ is angle $\in (-\pi;\pi]$ but i didn't found that notion in lots of books i just found reference angle
 ([James_Stewart,_Lothar_Redlin,_Saleem_Watson] Precalculus ) but it's not what i'm looking for

[image]

Comment: I would say the "principal angle (measure)" -- certainly "principal" is the preferred term in cases such as the argument or natural logarithm of a complex number, where the same underlying problem applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In complex analysis, this is commonly referred to as the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Principal_value) between two nonzero complex numbers. In general, if you wrote "the principal value $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$ of the angle between $v$ and $w$" for $v$ and $w$ in $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$, mathematicians would know what you mean.

Comment: Thanks could you suggest me some reference book for 'principal angle'

Comment: I'm away from my office or I'd give you an exact reference, but most introductory textbooks on complex analysis will use this terminology at some point. I can provide a specific reference later if need be.

Comment: yes please and thanks so much

Comment: Happy to help! It's more than you need but Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis should include it somewhere. I can't vouch for a more basic reference from personal experience

Comment: it's okay thanks again